# DataModel merging for apps from different projects in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, xcdatamodel

Customer has iPhone app on appstore. Second version of this app was developed from the beginning. Apps have absolutely different data models and when we try to update app with new version it crashes on using core data. In normal situation I would merge models, but what should I do if I don't have source model in my project?

Answer (score 0):

If your new model is completely changed I would say just leave the old model alone and start using new model.

you don't have to merge as long as you are not using old model and you can not use same name for new model.

Comment: The problem is that I have different entities with same name

Comment: you can delete entities from old model as you not using old model so they will not be accessed anywhere.